# Setter being told it hasn't be created but it has

Tags: java, setter

pretty much I've made a program that goes a little like this

1. Players are added to an array
2. they are then all placed against each other(just like a football match, every team plays every team)
3. They are then randomized
4. the program should display the end result(if you win a game you get 3 points) etc..

I keep getting a message from Eclipse saying ".setScore has NOT been coded..

TestGame.java

```
public class TestGame {
    static Players ceri = new Players("Ceri", 0);

    static Players harry = new Players("Harry", 0);
    static Players matthew = new Players("Matthew", 0);
    static Players james = new Players("James",0);
    static Players kwok = new Players("Kwok",0);
    static Players lewis = new Players("Lewis",0 );
    static Game League = new Game();
    int Ceri = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        League.addPlayers(ceri);
        League.addPlayers(matthew);
        League.addPlayers(james);
        League.addPlayers(kwok);
        League.addPlayers(lewis);
        League.addPlayers(harry);
        League.randomize();
        League.Results();    
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game extends TestGame {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Players[] people = new Players[6];
    private int counter = 0;
    List<String> Matches = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addPlayers(Players obj){
        people[counter] = obj;
        counter++;
        System.out.println(obj.getName());
    }

    public String randomize(){
        for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < people.length; j++){
                if(people[i].equals(people[j].getName())){                    
                    continue;
                } else {
                    Matches.add(people[i].getName() + " V " + people[j].getName());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String Results(){
        while(!Matches.isEmpty()){
            int Game = (int)(Math.random() * Matches.size());
            String Verses = (String)Matches.get(Game);

            System.out.println(Verses);
            System.out.println("Who has won?");

            String name = s.nextLine();
            //**ISSUE LIES HERE**    

            if(Verses.contains(name)){
                if(name == "ceri"){
                    ceri.setScore(3);
                } else if(name == "harry"){
                    harry.setScore(3);
                }else if (name == "matthew"){
                    matthew.setScore(3)
                } else if(name == "lewis"){
                    lewis.setScore(3)
                }else if ( name == "james"){
                    james.setScore(3)
                }else if(name == "kwok"){
                    kwok.setScore(3);
                }
            }

            Matches.remove(Game);
            System.out.println(one);

            return null;

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**WHERE ECLIPSE SAYS .setScore ISNT.**

Players.java

```
public class Players {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Players(String name, int score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score =+ score;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `==` instead of `.equals`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @jhobbie I know how .equals works etc but why wont the setter work?

Comment: Also, what is the type of the variables `ceri, harry, mathew,` etc.?  Where and how are they declared?  That could be affecting the compiler's errors.

Comment: @user3870022 it won't work because `name == "ceri"` doesn't do anything. Same thing for all your other names. And by doesn't do anything, I mean it doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: Well I thought i'd just jump the gun and try to change the 'points' by doing .setScore if that makes sense? @markspace

Comment: @jhobbie It might work in a simple program like this because all string constants are interned.  Let's get the program to compile first, then debug runtime issues.  (I do totally agree it's a bad habit though.)

Comment: @jhobbie , I guess i didn't know what it meant haha, so just change it to something like name.equals(ceri.getName)?

Comment: In which class do you have the match logic. Can't understand how the match logic access ceri, harry, mathew,

Comment: OK I see the definitions now.  You got me.  I think there's something else wrong (not shown) that is messing you up.  Like package names or similar.  Can you produce a short, complete example that shows the problem?  Just make one user and call .setScore() in a two line program, does that compile?

Comment: @Vwin the match logic is in game.java(if thats what you are asking)

Comment: I can't find the variable `Player ceri;` in your code. How are you calking `ceri.setScore`?

Comment: I think you're trying to reference `ceri` from an object with no reference to it.  If you paste the exact error you're getting, it might be helpful

Comment: the method for setScore is undefined for type Players @Gus

Comment: Keeping the static keywords in place, try `TestGame.ceri.setScore(3);` etc. for each player.

Comment: it comes up "change ceri to static"(which it already is) @RussellUhl

Comment: sorry.  also forgot to mention that you should make them `public static` (at least for now), just to rule out any accessibility issues.  (That may or may not fix the problem, but it will at least remove a variable from your problem)

Comment: unfortunately it hasnt sorted the issue </3 Thank you anyway! @RussellUhl

Comment: @RussellUhl i spoke too soon, it has!

Comment: Good.  I'll write it up in answer form for reference

Comment: I thank thee so much @RussellUhl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there are compile errors.  Please see merlin2011's answer for reference.

As to your actual issue, your Players (ceri, harry, matthew, etc.) are static members of TestGame...but are not publicly exposed.  This means that other objects can't see them, and so can't access them.  Add the `public` keyword to them:

```
public class TestGame {
    public static Players ceri = new Players("Ceri", 0);
    public static Players harry = new Players("Harry", 0);
    public static Players matthew = new Players("Matthew", 0);
    public static Players james = new Players("James",0);
    public static Players kwok = new Players("Kwok",0);
    public static Players lewis = new Players("Lewis",0 );

    ...
}
```

Now that they are publicly exposed, you need to reference them correctly.  Your Game class doesn't know what ceri is when you call `setScore(3)`, Since it is not a member of that class.  Instead, you need to tell it where ceri is located; in your TestGame class.  For reference, I've also used the traditional string equality comparison function.

```
if(name.equals("ceri")){
    TestGame.ceri.setScore(3);
}
```

Use this format for the other IF statements you have.

Comment: one last question, all of a sudden now my program terminates after one match is asked.. hmm

Comment: @user3870022  yep.  You have a return null inside your while loop in in your Game class.

Comment: @user3870022: one of the best tools at your disposal is the Debugger.  Learn how to use it, at least at a basic level.  It can allow you to run your code line by line, view and change variables mid-run, and a bunch of other things.  If you were to have used the debugger, you would have found that return null very quickly

Answer (score 1):

All the players are static members of TestGame class. They can access only static methods of Players now. So that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: ive changed them all from static now i'm getting errors because "League" is static as well, and then i take static off that and more errors

Comment: While your answer is truthfully correct, it also suggests that making something static makes it invisible to other objects, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues, but neither of them is related to setScore not being defined.

1. You are missing semicolons in the following block.

   ```
   if(Verses.contains(name)){
       if(name == "ceri"){
           ceri.setScore(3);
       } else if(name == "harry"){
           harry.setScore(3);
       }else if (name == "matthew"){
           matthew.setScore(3)
       } else if(name == "lewis"){
           lewis.setScore(3)
       }else if ( name == "james"){
           james.setScore(3)
           }else if(name == "kwok"){
           kwok.setScore(3);
       }
   }
   ```
2. You are not using `equals` for String comparison in the block above.

Here is a corrected version:

```
if(Verses.contains(name)){
    if(name.equals("ceri")){
        ceri.setScore(3);
    } else if(name.equals("harry")){
        harry.setScore(3);
    } else if (name.equals("matthew")){
        matthew.setScore(3);
    } else if(name.equals("lewis")){
        lewis.setScore(3);
    } else if ( name.equals("james")){
        james.setScore(3);
    } else if(name.equals("kwok")){
        kwok.setScore(3);
    }
}
```